# Unable to hide UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a view that is accessible in two different ways. I have an if statement that determines in which case a button should be displayed.

```
if([Recipes entryExists:[note recipeIdentifier]]){
    [buttons insertObject:btnRemoveFave atIndex:0];
    [btnPrefs setHidden:NO];
} else {
    [buttons insertObject:btnAddFave atIndex:0];
    [btnPrefs setHidden:YES];
    [btnPrefs setEnabled:NO];
}
```

I have placed a break point in the in both conditions of the if statement. When code enters the else condition, the lines that 'setHidden' and 'setEnabled' ARE both executed, yet the button is still visible AND enabled.

Any ideas as to why I can't disable the button? Thanks!

Comment: If you log btnPrefs, is it non-nil?

Comment: No, btnPrefs is not nil

Comment: How/where do you call the code you posted?

Comment: If that code is called, as you say, and btnPrefs is not nil, then I'm guessing that you have two different instance of the controller where this button is, and the one you see on screen is not the one where you have this code. Show how you get to the controller where you have this code.

Comment: Have you tried continuing from the breakpoint? The button will only hide after the next layout pass, not directly after calling setHidden.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if you are creating a new instance of the button each time you call the statement?
If you are using a local variable instead of instance, use the tag property to identify your button, so you can find it in the buttons array.

Besides that, I prefer using `alpha=0.0` instead of `hidden=YES`.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code. It's working for me.

For Remove:

```
[btnPrefs removeFromSuperview];
```

Then Add:

```
[self.view addSubview:btnPrefs];
```